# Docker : How to avoid Operation not permitted in Docker Container?

Tags: docker, permissions, suse

I created one docker image of sles12 machine by taking backing of all file system which are necessary and created one tar file. For creating docker image I run following command -

```
cat fullbackup.tar | docker import - sles_image
```

After that I run docker image in container using below command -

```
docker run --net network1 -i -t sles_image /bin/bash
```

note - I already set up networking in this docker container (IP address which I want).

Now In my docker container, some applications are already configured because that applications are available in sles12 machine from which I created this docker image. These custom applications are internally running some kernel low level commands like [modprobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modprobe).

But when I starts my application, application will start correctly. I'm facing this error -

> Operation not permitted

How I can give correct permissions so that it will not give me this error?

Answer (score 46):

You might try set the Docker container with [Runtime privilege and Linux capabilities](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities), with the

> docker run --privileged

Comment: Confirmed working using host network interfaces directly. Initially had `ifconfig enp0s8 192.168.55.4; ifconfig: SIOCSIFADDR: Operation not permitted`. Running with --privileged solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on mac resolve the issue by [giving  files and folder permissions](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchld5a35146/mac) to docker or the other workaround is to manually [copying the files to docker](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-copy-files-from-host-to-docker-container) instead of mounting them.

Comment: This is a fantastic find and really helped me out. Cheers!